# $query_args for loop to only get posts from "current category"?

Tags: wp-query

I've ran into trouble, i do not understand how to make my custom query respect the current category i'm browsing.

Lets say i'm in category "test1" and i have this custom query loop:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;   
$query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array('private', 'publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'paged' => $paged,
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );   
   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :     
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

This will take all posts that are private/publish and show them on all pages, even if i am browsing a category..... How do i add some a custom query that respect the current category?

If i add `cat'=> '1',` and specify a category, it obviously only grabs the category i specify.

I've desperately tried to use in house functions such as:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
echo $category->term_id;
```

inside the `'cat'=> '',` statement but that obviously doesn't work. I've also tried to use php if / else statments inside the array in hopes of being able to generate the category id based on where i am browsing on the site such as:

```
if (is_category(1)) { 
'cat' => '1', } else { 'cat' => '12', }
```

How do i go about solving this?

Comment: Assuming you are doing more than just trying to display posts for a category, yes?   Otherwise you would just use the category archive template and not need a query at all. https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: I am trying display published and private posts using this query on all pages except tag pages, i have solved so tag pages use a different query (the original one) but my custom query will not take the category into consideration, i've gotten a little bit further since i posted: i added $category = get_the_category(); $category_id = $category[0]->cat_ID; 'cat' => $category_id, to my custom query and now it takes the category into consideration, only one problem, if a post has more than 1 category in current category it also takes those categories into consideration, this is not what i wanted.

Comment: i guess i could create one template file per category and insert the query hardcoded into each category page but it's a little unpractical if i make changes to the theme later i have to edit as many files as i have categories

Comment: if you don't actually need an additional query, you can use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify the main query without editing the template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using the built in template hierarchy to solve this issue.